# Lenovo built-in cam is not working on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, lenovo, skype, webcam

I am facing an issue on my *Lenovo-E450 ThinkPad* with the built-in webcam. I am unable to use it with facebook/skype video call. I have already tried

```
sudo apt-get install cheese
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` libsbigudrv2 libsbigudrv0
```

Please help me how to use my built-in cam on Ubuntu 16.04. 
When I type `cheese` in the terminal it displays `No device found`

I am new to Ubuntu and don't know much about commands. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the output of `lshw`

```
 description: Notebook
product: 20DC003MUS (LENOVO_MT_20DC_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPad E450)
vendor: LENOVO
version: ThinkPad E450
serial: PF09Y9SA
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 vsyscall32

  configuration: administrator_password=disabled 
  chassis=notebook      family=ThinkPad E450
  power-on_password=disabled sku=LENOVO_MT_20DC_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPad E450 uuid=81466B8D-F253-CB11-B6A3-CE11FE88AE12

    *-core
   description: Motherboard
   product: 20DC003MUS
   vendor: LENOVO
   physical id: 0
   version: SDK0E50512 STD
   serial: L1HF56300KD
   slot: Not Available

    *-cache
      description: L1 cache
      physical id: 3
      slot: L1 Cache
      size: 32KiB
      capacity: 32KiB
      capabilities: synchronous internal write-back data
      configuration: level=1

      *-cpu
      description: CPU
      product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-5005U CPU @ 2.00GHz
      vendor: Intel Corp.
      physical id: 4
      bus info: cpu@0
      version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-5005U CPU @ 2.00GHz
      serial: None
      slot: U3E1
      size: 2GHz
      capacity: 2GHz
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 100MHz

      capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb intel_pt tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rdseed adx smap xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts cpufreq
      configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4

         *-cache:0
         description: L1 cache
         physical id: 5
         slot: L1 Cache
         size: 32KiB
         capacity: 32KiB
         capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
         configuration: level=1

        *-cache:1
         description: L2 cache
         physical id: 6
         slot: L2 Cache
         size: 256KiB
         capacity: 256KiB
         capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
         configuration: level=2

         *-cache:2
         description: L3 cache
         physical id: 7
         slot: L3 Cache
         size: 3MiB
         capacity: 3MiB
         capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
         configuration: level=3

       *-memory
      description: System Memory
      physical id: 8
      slot: System board or motherboard
      size: 8GiB

         *-bank:0
         description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
         product: 16KTF1G64HZ-1G6E1
         vendor: Micron
         physical id: 0
         serial: 22452413
         slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
         size: 8GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)

         *-bank:1
         description: DIMM [empty]
         physical id: 1
         slot: ChannelB-DIMM0

       *-firmware
      description: BIOS
      vendor: LENOVO
      physical id: 31
      version: J5ET44WW (1.15 )
      date: 03/12/2015
      size: 128KiB
      capacity: 15MiB
      capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi

      *-pci
      description: Host bridge
      product: Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 100
      bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
      version: 09
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      configuration: driver=bdw_uncore
      resources: irq:0

        *-display
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 09
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
         configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
         resources: irq:44 memory:e0000000-e0ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:3000(size=64)

          *-multimedia:0
         description: Audio device
         product: Broadwell-U Audio Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
         version: 09
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
         resources: irq:48 memory:e1230000-e1233fff

         *-usb:0
         description: USB controller
         product: Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 14
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
         version: 03
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:40 memory:e1220000-e122ffff

            *-usbhost:0
            product: xHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 4.4.0-53-generic xhci-hcd
            physical id: 0
            bus info: usb@3
            logical name: usb3
            version: 4.04
            capabilities: usb-3.00
            configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=5000Mbit/s

            *-usbhost:1
            product: xHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 4.4.0-53-generic xhci-hcd
            physical id: 1
            bus info: usb@2
            logical name: usb2
            version: 4.04
            capabilities: usb-2.00
            configuration: driver=hub slots=11 speed=480Mbit/s

               *-usb:0 UNCLAIMED
               description: Generic USB device
               product: VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
               vendor: Validity Sensors, Inc.
               physical id: 6
               bus info: usb@2:6
               version: 0.78
               serial: 5badf6af129e
               capabilities: usb-1.10
               configuration: maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s

               *-usb:1 UNCLAIMED
               description: Video
               product: Integrated Camera
               vendor: Generic
               physical id: 8
               bus info: usb@2:8
               version: 0.11
               serial: 200901010001
               capabilities: usb-2.00
               configuration: maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s

         *-communication
         description: Communication controller
         product: Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 16
         bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
         version: 03
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
         resources: irq:45 memory:e1239000-e123901f

        *-network
         description: Ethernet interface
         product: Ethernet Connection (3) I218-V
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 19
         bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
         logical name: enp0s25
         version: 03
         serial: 68:f7:28:df:f0:77
         capacity: 1Gbit/s
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz

         capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation

           configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.2-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair

           resources: irq:43 memory:e1200000-e121ffff memory:e123e000-e123efff ioport:3080(size=32)

         *-multimedia:1
         description: Audio device
         product: Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1b
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
         version: 03
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
         resources: irq:47 memory:e1234000-e1237fff

         *-pci:0
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
         version: e3
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz

         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:16

         *-pci:1
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
         version: e3
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz

         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:18 memory:e1100000-e11fffff

       *-network
            description: Wireless interface
            product: Wireless 3160
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
            logical name: wlp4s0
            version: 93
            serial: 34:e6:ad:36:d2:06
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz

            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless

            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-53-generic firmware=17.352738.0 ip=192.168.10.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn

            resources: irq:46 memory:e1100000-e1101fff
         *-pci:2
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c.5
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.5
         version: e3
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:17 memory:e1000000-e10fffff

       *-generic
            description: Unassigned class
            product: RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
            version: 01
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=rtsx_pci latency=0
            resources: irq:41 memory:e1000000-e1000fff

         *-usb:1
         description: USB controller
         product: Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1d
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
         version: 03
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
         resources: irq:23 memory:e123d000-e123d3ff

            *-usbhost
            product: EHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 4.4.0-53-generic ehci_hcd
            physical id: 1
            bus info: usb@1
            logical name: usb1
            version: 4.04
            capabilities: usb-2.00
            configuration: driver=hub slots=3 speed=480Mbit/s

               *-usb
               description: USB hub
               vendor: Intel Corp.
               physical id: 1
               bus info: usb@1:1
               version: 0.03
               capabilities: usb-2.00
               configuration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=480Mbit/s

         *-isa
         description: ISA bridge
         product: Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
         version: 03
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
         resources: irq:0

         *-storage
         description: SATA controller
         product: Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
         version: 03
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz

         capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list

         configuration: driver=ahci latency=0

         resources: irq:42 ioport:30a8(size=8) 
        ioport:30b4(size=4) ioport:30a0(size=8) ioport:30b0(size=4) 
        ioport:3060(size=32) memory:e123c000-e123c7ff

         *-serial UNCLAIMED
         description: SMBus
         product: Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
         version: 03
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:e1238000-e12380ff ioport:efa0(size=32)

         *-generic
         description: Signal processing controller
         product: Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.6
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
         version: 03
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=intel_pch_thermal latency=0
         resources: irq:18 memory:e123b000-e123bfff

       *-scsi
      physical id: 0
      logical name: scsi0
      capabilities: emulated

        *-disk
         description: ATA Disk
         product: SAMSUNG SSD PM83
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/sda
         version: 2D1Q
         serial: S0TYNYABB89935
         size: 119GiB (128GB)
         capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
         configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=4aa7759e

            *-volume:0
            description: EXT4 volume
            vendor: Linux
            physical id: 1
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
            logical name: /dev/sda1
            logical name: /
            version: 1.0
            serial: 163228d1-4309-4d03-a060-e518ebc1b150
            size: 111GiB
            capacity: 111GiB

            capabilities: primary bootable journaled 

            extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink 
           recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized

            configuration: created=2016-11-09 22:56:50 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2016-12-25 16:28:30 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2016-12-25 16:28:31 state=mounted

       *-volume:1
            description: Extended partition
            physical id: 2
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
            logical name: /dev/sda2
            size: 7925MiB
            capacity: 7925MiB

            capabilities: primary extended partitioned   
            partitioned:extended


          *-logicalvolume
               description: Linux swap / Solaris partition
               physical id: 5
               logical name: /dev/sda5
               capacity: 7925MiB
               capabilities: nofs

       *-battery
        product: LNV-45N1
   vendor: SMP
   physical id: 1
   slot: Front
   capacity: 47500mWh
   configuration: voltage=11.3V
```

Output of `lsusb --verbose -s 2:8`

[image]

Output of `lsusb`

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  **;-)** what's the output to `lshw`? [edit] your question to provide the info there.  Are you sure the camera is turned on in Hardware?

Comment: Thank you @Fabby i have edited my question with output of *lshw*. please have a look.

Comment: Found it: `-usb:1 UNCLAIMED description: Video product: Integrated Camera`, so no module is installed.  Please provide the output of `lsusb --verbose -s 2:8`

Comment: Hello, from your `lshw` output, we can tell that your webcam is connected to usb, can you please update the question with `lsusb` command? So that we could know what is the product id, thanks

Comment: Thank You @P.-H.Lin, I have edited my question with output of `lsusb`. Please suggest me.

Comment: @P.-H.Lin Thank you very much for detailed guide lines, i have reviewed that answer. lemme know how can i update my kernal ? Thanks in advance.